# Numpy for Windows with python 3.6

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, windows-7, pycharm

I installed PyCharm as Python IDE on Windows 7 (I use Python 3.6). Now I try to install some packages for example numpy.
In the first way, I go to:

> File -> Settings -> Project

and tried to install (with the + Button) a new Package (numpy). But then I get the failure message:

> "Non-zero exit code (1)"

As proposed solution I get:

> "Try to run this command from the system terminal. Make sure that you
>   use the correct version of 'pip' installed for your Python interpreter
>   located at 'C:\Program Files\Python36\python.exe'."

In this case: "this command" maybe means:

> pip install numpy

I tried this, but I get the same error.

Then I saw this page:
http://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/
I downloaded the package: "numpy-1.11.2rc1+mkl-cp27-cp27m-win_amd64.whl" unziped this and pasted this new folder in the .../Python36/Lib/ folder.

However, PyCharm may be detect numpy, but I get this error yet:

```
"C:\Program Files\Python36\python.exe" "D:/Dropbox/Dropbox/Python/Eigene Übungen/HelloWorld/numpyUebungen.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/Python/Eigene Übungen/HelloWorld/numpyUebungen.py", line 1, in <module>
    import numpy as np
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\numpy\__init__.py", line 142, in <module>
    from . import add_newdocs
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\numpy\add_newdocs.py", line 13, in <module>
    from numpy.lib import add_newdoc
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\numpy\lib\__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from .type_check import *
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\numpy\lib\type_check.py", line 11, in <module>
    import numpy.core.numeric as _nx
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\numpy\core\__init__.py", line 14, in <module>
    from . import multiarray
ImportError: DLL load failed: Das angegebene Modul wurde nicht gefunden.

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Does anybody know, what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks in advance and best regards,
Matthias

Comment: `numpy-1.11.2rc1+mkl-cp27-cp27m-win_amd64.whl` is a binary package that will only work with Python 2.7. Use the package that matches your python version, namely `numpy‑1.11.3+mkl‑cp36‑cp36m‑win_amd64.whl` which has been released by Christoph Gohlke in the mean time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. first check your path of environment variable in advanced setting
2. if it is not there add two paths C:\Python27 and C:\Python27\Scripts
3. then with the help of command prompt use the command as "pip install numpy"  or use "easy_install numpy"

Comment: Hello,
thank you. I tried this, but with Python 36 it doesn't work. I tried C:\Python27 and C:\Python27 the same for the second path variable. I get some error messages. Then I installed Python 2.7 and it works. :)

Thanks and best regards, Matthias

Comment: 3.6 is a development version - some stage of early beta.  Stick with 3.5 if you want all 3rd party packages.

Comment: Thanks, nice to know. :)

Answer (score 0):

1. Open a console window by pressing <kbd>Windows</kbd> + <kbd>r</kbd>
   and then typing in *cmd*. Hit <kbd>Return</kbd>
2. Into the conole window type: `cd C:\Program Files\Python36\`
3. then type: `pip install
   C:\Users\my_name\Downloads\numpy‑1.14.0+mkl‑cp36‑cp36m‑win_amd64.whl`
   which you downloaded from [here](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#numpy) before.

The problems before were, that the wrong version of numpy was downloaded (cp27 instead of cp36) and (probably) that `pip` for the wrong python version was used (Thats why we switch to the local folder first).